# Google Plus Sign in with Django-Allauth

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-allauth

In django-allauth, I am trying to use google plus sign in (as recommended by google - https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login) instead of the standard google Oauth2 sign in.

For the most part I have this working -- I changed the SCOPE to be `googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` instead of `googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile`, and the user is able to authenticate with google plus. However, I am unable to get some user data such as first name and last name.

Looking at the code, I believe this is because of the `profile_url` within the `GoogleOAuth2Adapter` class. To work with Google plus it should be `googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me` instead of `googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo`.

Is there a way to override the `profile_url` or is there another workaround?